# How to flip only some parts of an image

Tags: gimp, images, image-editing

I have several images with text on them. I would like to "ONLY" flip the texts in the images. Here is an example:

[image]

I want to keep the image intact except the texts where I need to flip them horizontally.

What is the easiest way to achieve that in Gimp? If not, are there any other free tools that could help me achieve that?

Thank you

Comment: If you do not have to do a lot of these, you could erase the text from the image and write new text using the text tool. Otherwise you could make a selection, copy it to a new layer and flip that layer.

Comment: To be honest i would just redraw the image.

Comment: I agree with @joojaa redrawing would result in much better quality and take (probably) less time than covering the existing text - either way you'll need to rekey the text.

Answer (score 1):

Make a rectangle selection around the text and use the Flip tool ([image]) to flip the selection then Ctrl-H (or the Anchor icon at the bottom of the layers list) to "anchor" the result:

[image]

Caveats:

- the content of the selection are cut and flipped, so if you want the result to fit the holed created in the source the selection has to be symmetrical (rectangle or ellipse)
- everything in the selection is flipped, so if there are other items in the "bounding box" of the text they will be flipped with it. So "Pompe de massage" can be handled as a whole, but "boîtier pneumatique" has to be done in two steps, one for each line, and "Aspiration" will be complicated.